# JSON response in a listView

Tags: android, json, sencha-touch, listitem

I am learning secha touch, I want to create a page where after user enter login credentials the JSON response will be received which is as follows

```
  {"items":[{"id":"78e221c8-bbc1-4754-8471-48c863886869","createTime":"2014-05-22T14:57:39.039Z","createUser":"Jon","status":"SAVED","changeTime":"2014-05-22T14:57:39.039Z","changeUser":"Jon","projectId":"63886869-bbc1-4754-8471-48c878e221c8","reportVersionNumber":"1","reportVersionName":"First Version","reportName":"FooBarBaz","reportHash":"qiyh4XPJGsOZ2MEAyLkfWqeQ"}],"totalItems":1

}
```

currently i have created a page where i have used a listItem and displaying the items in it from the Simple array where data has been given harcoded 
and using itemTPL to get it
like this `<div class="arHeadline">{projectId}`

my current store is

```
 data: [
                {
                    Headline: 'Panel',
                    Author: 'Sencha',
                    Content: 'Panels are most useful as Overlays - containers that float over your appl..'
            }
```

but i want to get the data from the json so i created a JSON store

```
Ext.define('MobileChecklist.store.MyJsonPStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'MobileChecklist.model.MyModel',
        'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json',
        'Ext.data.Field'
    ],

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        data: [
            {
                items: [
                    {
                        id: '78e221c8-bbc1-4754-8471-48c863886869',
                        createTime: '2014-05-22T14:57:39.039Z',
                        createUser: 'Jon',
                        status: 'SAVED',
                        changeTime: '2014-05-22T14:57:39.039Z',
                        changeUser: 'Jon',
                        projectId: '63886869-bbc1-4754-8471-48c878e221c8',
                        reportVersionNumber: '1',
                        reportVersionName: 'First Version',
                        reportName: 'FooBarBaz',
                        reportHash: 'qiyh4XPJGsOZ2MEAyLkfWqeQ'
                    }
                ],
                totalItems: 1
            }
        ],
        model: 'MobileChecklist.model.MyModel',
        storeId: 'MyJsonPStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'data/getPort.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                idProperty: 'id',
                rootProperty: 'items',
                totalProperty: 'totalItems',
                record: 'items'
            }
        },
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'reportName'
            },
            {
                name: 'projectId'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

and my model is

```
Ext.define('MobileChecklist.model.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.Field'
    ],

    config: {
        fields: [
            {
                mapping: 'items.reportName',
                name: 'reportName',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                mapping: 'items.projectId',
                name: 'projectId',
                type: 'string'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

I want to decode the json response and display it in the ListItem the way i did with the string array
how can I do it please help

EDIT:
if I remove the items from my json response and make it like an array rather than object it works and displays it in the list view

```
[{"id":"78e221c8-bbc1-4754-8471-48c863886869","createTime":"2014-05-22T14:57:39.039Z","createUser":"Jon","status":"SAVED","changeTime":"2014-05-22T14:57:39.039Z","changeUser":"Jon","projectId":"63886869-bbc1-4754-8471-48c878e221c8","reportVersionNumber":"1","reportVersionName":"First Version","reportName":"FooBarBaz","reportHash":"qiyh4XPJGsOZ2MEAyLkfWqeQ"}],"totalItems":1}]
```

Comment: In your store set data.items and your problem will be solved and you don't have to map the datas in your model as well.

Comment: what should i set the data.items? the mapping or url or something else? i set both of this didn't help me @SujataChanda

Comment: @SujataChanda please see the edit and if you get anything please help me, thanks

Comment: So your problem is solved then. What do you want beside that?

Comment: my problem is not solved i dont want to modify my JSON response if i change it i am getting the response so the problem is that the itms are not getting mapped

Comment: @SujataChanda if i change the response as given in the edit m getting response but i dont want to change it I want output with the same response as mentioned in the begining of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the store data with `data.items` in your controller, like this: -

```
       Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: someurl,
            params: {
                format: "json"
            },
            success: function(response) {
               Ext.getStore("MyJsonPStore").setData(response.items);
            },
            failure: function(err) {
               console.log("Error", err);
            }
        });
```

This is the way to work with json data.

Found your problem, change your store proxy to this:-

```
 proxy: {
            type: 'rest',  //change it
            url: 'data/getPort.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                idProperty: 'id',
                rootProperty: 'items',
                totalProperty: 'totalItems'
            }
        }
```

No need to map the datas.

Comment: Now I got what u want to say but for testing purpose I have directly given the JSON response I am getting in the data which is as good as it is getting an ajax request response

Comment: now i want to map its items to the list view items but the items in response are inside {items:[ in the response if i take it out those gets mapped

Comment: sorry but this didnt help me, did u get my question properly??if not pls tell me i will explain it to you in a proper way? because m not moving ahead with this issue and i need your help

Comment: I ran your code and by changing the above line and giving a proper path for the url got the list successfully. I removed the fields property from store and removed the model mapping as well, instead made it `fields: ["reportName", "projectId"]`.

Comment: can you please mail me the code which you could run successfully?? because I am still not able to run the code with the changes you mentioned..:(

Comment: I am trying to send you the mail but its saying that your given mailId does not exists.

Comment: oh sorry id is shrinivas.v.pai@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks for your patience, time and concern

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with the secha touch framework before but JSON Parsing is quite simple. If you already have the JSON coming to your device, try this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

Then create an adapter to your ListView